# airflow fileSensor matching with specific file pattern

Tags: airflow

I'm using airflow, i have 1 dag which begin by a file sensor, it's working good, but i need a condition which is to match a certain pattern for files. I saw OmegaFileSensor but i cannot import it (maybe deprecated?). Is someone already use something like what i want?

my dag:

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

scriptAirflow = '/home/alexw/scriptAirflow/'
uploadPath= '/apps/lv-manuf2020-data/80_DATA/00_Loading/'


default_args = {
    'owner': 'manuf2020',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 2, 17),
    'retries': 1
}

dag = DAG('lv-manuf2020', default_args=default_args, description='airflow_manuf2020',
          schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)

sensor_file = FileSensor(
    task_id="sensor_file",
    filepath=uploadPath,
    fs_conn_id='airflow_db',
    dag=dag,
)
move_file = BashOperator(
    task_id="move_file",
    bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'movingFiles.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
    trigger_rule='one_success',
    dag=dag,
)

run_Sh_Script = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_scriptSh',
    bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'runShScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
    dag=dag,
)

rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='rerun_dag',
    trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
    dag=dag,
)

move_file.set_upstream(sensor_file)
run_Sh_Script.set_upstream(sensor_file)
rerun_dag.set_upstream(sensor_file)
run_Sh_Script.set_upstream(move_file)
rerun_dag.set_upstream(move_file)
rerun_dag.set_upstream(run_Sh_Script)
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `FileSensor` operator uses `glob` module to match file patterns, you can use a file name pattern or a wildcard to achieve the same functionality as OmegaSensor operator

for example:

```py
uploadPath= '/apps/lv-manuf2020-data/80_DATA/00_Loading/*.ini'
```

the above will check for `ini` file in the directory.

for source code have a look here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/sensors/filesystem.py#L61

Comment: Thank you it can help me! for my case, files need to match with a startswith('string'), and i have 2 differents. can i do this?

Comment: you can always provide a wildcard like this: let's say you file starts with `file` and you have files like `filename1.txt`, `filename2.txt` then you can use `file*` wildcard. And to your second question create the same task (FileSensor) and use the second pattern. Keep both task-parallel and then connect both parallel ones to `run_Sh_Script`

Comment: I can't import that module anymore, is it deprecated?

Comment: which version of airflow you are using?

Comment: airflow v1.10.9, but when you answered my question it's worked